# jQuery Mobile: prevent anchor clicks in scrollview (if scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, anchor, scrollview

I have a jQuery Mobile application with a scrollview in the body of the page. The scrollview contains links. I'd like, if scrolling, to prevent the click of the scrollview from triggering a link when the user's cursor releases over a link.

I understand jQuery uses bubbling (bottom-up, or inside-out) as opposed to capturing (top-down, or outside-in). And I don't have .click() handlers on the links, they are just HREFs. So I guess I can't use something like stopPropagation() on the event since a mousedown or click event has already gotten to my scrollview by the time I can catch it.

There are events in the jQuery Mobile scrollview plugin I'm using where I can hook into drag start, drag handle and drag stop events. How could I conditionally see if the user is scrolling and somehow absorb or cancel the contained anchor clicks in that case?

Comment: What scrollview plugin are you using?  This doesn't happen in jQuery Mobile by default.

Comment: It's something called jquery.mobile.scrollview.js. It looks like something that used to be a plugin for jQuery or jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I wound up ditching the scrollview plugin, which came with an older jQuery Mobile theme I found. It was authored by someone at Adobe, but apparently termed as "experimental" and has since been abandoned. Regular divs with overflow: scroll work fine.